# Contour integration $\frac{e^{iz}}{2\sqrt{z}}$

Tags: contour-integration

When $z=u+iv$,

[image]

I would like to compute the integral of $\frac{e^{iz}}{2\sqrt{z}}$ along above curve.

1. The imaginary axis
   $$\frac{1}{2}\int_{R}^{0} \frac{e^{-v}}{\sqrt{iv}}d(iv)$$
   $R$ goes to $\infty$.

Here because of $\sqrt{iv}$. I confuse to use the change of variable $v=y^{2}$.
Anyone can helps me about this?

2. the integral over the circular arc goes to zero as $R\rightarrow \infty$. How can I show it?

Comment: What is $\sqrt{iv}$?

Comment: since the part is on the imaginary axis, when $z=u+iv$, $\frac{e^{iz}}{2\sqrt{z}}$ can be written in $\frac{e^{-v}}{2\sqrt{iv}}$

Comment: Are you sure that that is an answer to my question?

Comment: $i^\frac1{2}=\left(e^{\pi i/2}\right)^\frac1{2}=e^{\pi i/4}$ I can compute. Thanks for your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The integral converges, so you can already take the limit $R\rightarrow \infty$. As you mention, the change of variables $y=\sqrt{v}$ yields a gaussian integral you can simply evaluate.
2. Generally for the function $\frac{e^{iz}}{z^s}$ with $s>0$ you can proceed as follows: Parametrize $z=Re^{it}$ with $t\in[0,\pi/2]$. Then
   $$\left| \int_C \frac{e^{iz}}{z^s} \, {\rm d}z \right| \leq R^{1-s} \int_0^{\pi/2} e^{-R\sin(t)} \, {\rm d}t \stackrel{\sin(t)\geq 2t/\pi}{\leq} R^{1-s} \int_0^{\pi/2} e^{-2Rt/\pi} \, {\rm d}t \, .$$

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. Can you more explain to me how the first inequality hold? ($\left| \int_C \frac{e^{iz}}{z^s} \, {\rm d}z \right| \leq R^{1-s} \int_0^{\pi/2} e^{-R\sin(t)} \, {\rm d}t $).

Comment: This is the standard estimate (Cauchy Schwarz).